# Как прижать один элемент по горизонтали вправо с помощью flexbox, не затрагивая остальные элементы?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Не могу прижать один блок к правой стороне с помощью флексбокс, помогите.

Кода у меня нет, просто я не знаю как это сделать.

Как управлять одним единственным элементов по горизонтали во flexbox?

Нужно прижать блок header__contacts вправо на медиа запросах

```
.header__top-inner {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}

.header__navigation {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.header__contacts {
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'MuseoSansCyrl-900';
    font-size: 16px;
    background: url(../img/header_contacts-icon.png) no-repeat left center;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Добавь картинки, как бы ты хотел чтобы это выглядело. в контейнере у тебя только один элемент? Код у тебя точно есть, как минимум тот, который сейчас работает не так как ты ожидаешь, его тоже можно добавить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Последнему элементу можно указать `margin-left:auto`

```css
.c {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.el {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.el:last-child {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div class="el">1</div>
  <div class="el">2</div>
  <div class="el">3</div>
  <div class="el">4</div>
  <div class="el">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!